# Discard/Ignore the rest of a line form a file in c++

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to read only specific sets of data from a text file. Later I need to "feed" a class with it's content and store the objects in a vector.

My problem is, that I don't need the whole content of the lines and would like to discard or ignore what's coming next and jump to the next line of the text.

I would be very happy if you have a solution or tips for me :)

Each line in the file is structured like this:

> brand modelName yearOfProduction price moreStuffIDontCareAbout

Here's what I've come up with so far.

```
while (inputFile >> brand >> modell >> yearofproduction >> prize) {     
    vecBikes.push_back(Bike(brand, modell, yearofproduction, prize));
    getline(inputFile, puffer);
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? What's not working? What errors to you get?

Comment: Have you checked a [`std::istream` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)? I'm sure you will quickly find a function to *ignore* the remaining line.

Comment: once you read the line with `getline` you dont need to ignore it anymore because it was already read. not clear what is the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: What fails to work with your current solution?

Comment: It basically works for me but my main intention was, if there's a possibility to do it without reading the whole line, every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's say you have a class `Bike` defined as such.

```
struct Bike {
    std::string brand, model;
    int year, price;
};
```

Then I suggest you define an input operator for class `Bike`.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Bike& b) {
    if (std::string line; std::getline(in, line)) {
        std::istringstream line_stream{line};
        line_stream >> b.brand >> b.model >> b.year >> b.price;
    }
    return in;
}
```

<sup>(Note the use of the C++17 [if-with-initializers](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/08/cpp17-if-statement-with-initializer-steve-lorimer) syntax).</sup>

Now it is simply a matter of constructing an `std::istream_iterator` pair for filling your vector from any input stream (let's say the stream is called `input` here).

```
std::vector<Bike> vecBikes{std::istream_iterator<Bike>{input},
                        std::istream_iterator<Bike>{}};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/132a2534e745fde8)

Answer (score -1):

One can solution for this can be by putting delimiter charcter before part to be ignored.
And then setting the custom delimiter character, for `getline()` function
Code:

```
while (getline (inputFile,puffer,(delimiter))
{ 
 }
```

Comment: This way remaining text is still not consumed.